# Doesn't fire my custom textbox's mousewheel event

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a custom text box and I'm developing a notepad app. I want to dynamically write the zoom factor of the text box to the label. so I need to use the textbox mousewheel event but it doesn't light up so it doesn't go inside the mousewheel. what should I do ?

[first image for here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQlF3.png)

[second image for here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASWBp.png)

```
this.txtBoxKryptonText.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.txtBoxKryptonText_MouseWheel);

  private void txtBoxKryptonText_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
        int mousedeltaval = e.Delta / 120;

        if (mousedeltaval == 1) //mousewheel up move
        {
            txtBoxKryptonText.ZoomFactor += 0.1F;
            statusbarZoomState += 10;
            toolStripStatusZoom.Text = "%" + statusbarZoomState;
        }
        else if (mousedeltaval == -1) //mousewheel down move
        {
            txtBoxKryptonText.ZoomFactor -= 0.1F;
            statusbarZoomState -= 10;
            toolStripStatusZoom.Text = "%" + statusbarZoomState;
        }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should not post your code as images. Nobody can copy your code to try for them selfs.

Comment: Please replace these images with actual code snippets, if you wrap them in triple back-ticks it will automatically syntax highlight the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks ok to me.

Place your mouse pointer very close to the edge of the textbox and you'll see it works.

If you want to handle the events over the entire area you should probably do something like:

```
this.txtBoxKryptonText.ContainedControl.MouseWheel
  += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.txtBoxKryptonText_MouseWheel);
```